# Keep background image resolution in a webview

Tags: android, css, html, android-layout

I have an android webview created programmatically.

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {....}

final DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int screenWidth = Math.max(dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels);
int screenHeight = Math.min(dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels);
Log.e("TAG","Width "+screenWidth+" Height "+screenHeight); 

layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(screenWidth,screenHeight));            
webView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(screenWidth,screenHeight));

layout.addView(webView);
```

I have set the background image with CSS like this:

```
body
{
margin: auto;
padding: 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-image: url('image_480.png');}
```

I want for the webwiew to keep the background image as it is, without any scaling. If the device has a smaller resolution than the background image resolution, the rest of the background will be filled with some other color.

The image is not scaled when using a image with a smaller resolution than the screen resolution, but if I use an image with the exact same resolution as the screen, somehow the image is stretched. Any idea why this happens?

Also, even if I set the height and width of the web view, if I print the dimensions in JavaScript:

```
alert($(window).width());
alert($(window).height());
```

they are different form the one set.